# Bidisperse disk packing

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently writing an algorithm to generate bidisperse random close packed configurations of disks i.e. disk configurations with two different radii that touch.

The algorithm seems to correctly generate random close packed configurations. The issue I am having is that the trend for the packing fraction seems to be incorrect and I am unsure whether this is due to an issue with the code or is inherent to the algorithm.

(I would post images of some configurations generated but do not have the reputation required for this)

The packing fraction is calculated by finding the largest polygon with vertices corresponding to the outer disk positions, then finding the disk area contained within it and dividing this with the polygon area.

I have implemented the algorithm in Python using Numpy for array manipulation. After the algorithm has run there are `positions` and `sizes` arrays containing the disk positions and sizes respectively. There is a `largest_polygon` array containing the indices (as the disks are placed sequentially they are labelled from 0 to N) of the largest polygon. There is also a `total_disk_area` variable containing the total area of all the disks.

The code then does the following to find the packing fraction:

```
#Calculate area of cell
def area(indices, positions):
    A=0
    for i in range(0, len(indices)-2):
        x=positions[indices[i+2]]-positions[indices[i+1]]
        y=positions[indices[i+1]]-positions[indices[0]]
        
        A+=(0.5*(x[0]*y[1]-x[1]*y[0]))
        
    return round(abs(A), 5)

#Calculate angle between two vectors
def angle(v1, v2):
    if -v1[0]*v2[1]+v1[1]*v2[0] == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        sign=(-v1[0]*v2[1]+v1[1]*v2[0])/abs(v1[0]*v2[1]-v1[1]*v2[0])
        return(math.acos(np.dot(v1,v2)/(math.sqrt(np.dot(v1,v1)*np.dot(v2,v2))))*sign)

for i in range(len(largest_polygon)):
    theta=round(np.pi+angle(np.round(positions[largest_polygon[(i+1)%(len(largest_polygon))]]-positions[largest_polygon[i]],decimals=5), np.round(positions[largest_polygon[i]]-positions[largest_polygon[i-1]],decimals=5)),3)
    total_disk_area-=(theta)*(sizes[largest_polygon[i]]**2)*0.5

total_area=(area(largest_polygon, positions))

packing_fraction=(total_disk_area/total_area)
#print('Packing fraction: '+str(packing_fraction))
```

I.e. it subtracts the area of the disk not contained within the largest polygon using the angles between the polygon's edges and divides it by the polygon's area. Is there an alternative way to find the packing fraction as I am finding it difficult to test and debug my code? (If needed I post the full code)